# Can you choose the start point of an iterator in Python 3.4?

Tags: python, list, loops, python-3.x, iterator

Given this list:

```
numbers=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

My aim is to add these numbers one by one, and each in time doing so, I want to start adding from the  *nth* place, and save the result:

```
added=[]
num=[1,2,3,4,5]

for i in range(len(num)):
        add=itertools.accumulate([int (i) for i in num])
        added.append([i for i in add])

        num.insert(len(num),num[0])
        num.pop(0)

return added


>>>[[1, 3, 6, 10, 15], [2, 5, 9, 14, 15], [3, 7, 12, 13, 15], [4, 9, 10, 12, 15], [5, 6, 8, 11, 15]]
```

Each time I do this however, I also want to save from the *nth* position, like so:

```
[[1, 3, 6, 10, 15], [15, 2, 5, 9, 14], [13, 15, 3, 7, 12], [10, 12, 15, 4, 9], [6, 8, 11, 15, 5]]
```

The way to achieve this is quite tricky, but being able to choose the start point for *i* would make this procedure effortless, because no extra code (mainly other for loops) would need to be created to accommodate procedures such as this.

Just to be clear, I wish to ***save*** in the *nth* position, as in the second list of lists:

```
[[1, 3, 6, 10, 15], [2, 5, 9, 14, 15], [3, 7, 12, 13, 15], [4, 9, 10, 12, 15], [5, 6, 8, 11, 15]]
[[1, 3, 6, 10, 15], [15, 2, 5, 9, 14], [13, 15, 3, 7, 12], [10, 12, 15, 4, 9], [6, 8, 11, 15, 5]]
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Is this what you want? `for i in range(start, end, step)` e.g. `for i in range(2, 10, 2)` = `2, 4, 6, 8`

Comment: Her OdraEncoded, thanks for the help, but does that work for when you want to iterate over a sequence e.g a list and when you want to choose it's start point?

Comment: If you want to rotate the iterator, try this `itertools.accumulate([num[j % len(num)] for j in range(i, i + len(num))])`

Answer (score 2):

Using [`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice), [`itertools.cycle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle):

```
>>> from itertools import accumulate, islice, cycle
>>>
>>> numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> n = len(numbers)
>>> [list(accumulate(islice(cycle(numbers), i, i+n))) for i in range(n)]
[[1, 3, 6, 10, 15],
 [2, 5, 9, 14, 15],
 [3, 7, 12, 13, 15],
 [4, 9, 10, 12, 15],
 [5, 6, 8, 11, 15]]
```

Combining with [`collections.deque.rotate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque.rotate), you can get the final result:

```
>>> from collections import deque
>>> xs = [deque(accumulate(islice(cycle(numbers), i, i+n))) for i in range(n)]
>>> for i, x in enumerate(xs):
...     x.rotate(i)  # if i == 1, [1, 2, 3] become [3, 1, 2].
...
>>> [list(x) for x in xs]
[[1, 3, 6, 10, 15],
 [15, 2, 5, 9, 14],
 [13, 15, 3, 7, 12],
 [10, 12, 15, 4, 9],
 [6, 8, 11, 15, 5]]
```

Comment: Hey, thanks, but the real aim is to save in the nth position, which is the advantage of being able to choose the position of which i iterates from.

Comment: @user2901512, I updated the answer to include the code that yield the second list.

Comment: Bah - had almost exactly the same open in an editor - beat me to it +1

Answer (score 0):

Sure:

Say you have this list (as you specified):

```
numbers=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

And you want to start from 2, then you simply do:

```
numbers[2:]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can cycle the results through:

```
from itertools import islice, cycle, accumulate
num = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
added = []
for n in range(len(num)):
    added.append(list(islice(cycle(accumulate(islice(cycle(num),n,n+len(num)))),len(num)-n,2*len(num)-n)))
```